# Is main = return () a program?

Tags: haskell, assembly

I can't fit the definition of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program) with Haskell code:

```
main = return ()
```

or

```
main = undefined
```

Above all, "A computer program is a collection of instructions[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program)" where [instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) are defined like that.

Taking those two definition, is `main = return ()` a computer program? Is the definition quoting to machine code?

If it is... Why?
If it's not, what is considered a program in Haskell?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ah true. But suppose the statement was within the definition of `main`, to at least get it to compile. The rest of the question remains basically the same.

Comment: Be aware that a program is not required to *do* anything meaningful. An "empty" program that just returns to the caller would still qualify as valid implementation of `/bin/true`, for example. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar that's a really interesting observation indeed

Comment: @Alexander yes I see, `main = return ()` just "creates heat", as you say in your answer, yet is a valid (if useless) "program". Perhaps I took the question too literally.

Comment: @RobinZigmond You have got my point, I will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Even `main = return ()` isn't really a program. It's a module which defines a name expected by the runtime, and is used by the linker to produce a program.

Comment: "Computer program" isn't precise technical jargon, it's just a normal word, so its definition is flexible based on context. I would say `main = return ()` is absolutely a computer program. Haskell programs aren't exactly "sequences of instructions" either, they're more like "collections of definitions", but they are surely programs nonetheless. And all that "you have to compile and link" is technically true, but I would take it as assumed. You don't say "I'll write a haskell module which I will pass to a linker to create a program to do that", you just say "I'll write a program to do that".

Comment: I'm going with the OP's own definition of a computer program here.

Comment: But it's from the wikipedia article "Computer program", which is about the general concept rather than a precise mathematical definition.  My interpretation is that OP is taking things a bit too exactly and needs to relax about it, thus the point of my comment.

Comment: @DevSolar Speaking of which: http://trillian.mit.edu/~jc/humor/ATT_Copyright_true.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing about the definition of a program *requires* it to have explicit I/O. For example, consider `/bin/sleep`. It does literally nothing besides doing nothing for a fixed period of time. Ultimately, it does kind of have input/output, in that it "causes" (in a weak sense of the term) a change in the time.

Another example might be a Python program like:

```
while True:
    pass
```

All it does is create heat, literally, but there's no reason to think it's not a program.

An unoptimized build of your program might actually contain the machine instructions to load an immediate value `5` into some register, followed by program termination. However, an optimizing compiler like Haskell's would deduce that the value is never used, and will gladly cull it entirely (and it's more than free to do so, since it won't have any observable effect. The machine instructions for program termination would still exist, though.

Comment: In normal OSes, programs must make at least 1 system call (e.g. `_exit` or `exit_group` on a POSIX OS like Linux).  Or be an infinite loop.  Or terminate by faulting, e.g. with a segmentation fault or illegal instruction.  But anyway, `sleep(2)` is a system call.  Without system calls, `sleep(1)` could only be implemented with a busy-wait and then faulting. (On modern x86, the CPU hardware provides a real-time clock that's readable in userspace with a machine instruction, `rdtsc`, if your program contains enough logic to do CPU detection and work out the scale factor for ref cycles -> seconds)